# Flattening a complex list of tuples

Tags: list, python-3.x, tuples

I have a list of tuples, with nested tuples and lists, that looks like the list bellow:

```
 a= [('Maria', [1, [2, {'teste': (2, 1.0)}]]), 
('Lisa ', [2, [4, {'field': (4, 0.75), 'bola': (4, 0.25)}]]), 
('John ', [4, [5, {'engine': (5, 0.2), 'wheel': (5, 0.4), 'wheels': (5, 0.2)}]]),
 ('Tracy ', [4, [6, {'pizza': (6, 0.16), 'fish': (6, 0.1), 'animals': (6, 0.1)}]])]
```

I want to flat out this list to look like:

```
a.modified = ('Maria', 1, 2, {'teste': (2, 1.0)}]]), 
('Lisa ', 2, 4, {'field': (4, 0.75), 'bola': (4, 0.25)}]]), 
('John ', 4, 5, {'engine': (5, 0.2), 'wheel': (5, 0.4), 'wheels': (5, 0.2)}]]), 
('Tracy ', 4, 6, {'pizza': (6, 0.16), 'fish': (6, 0.1), 'animals': (6, 0.1}]])])
```

I have tried doing it step by step, using:

```
a2=[item for sublist in a for item in sublist]
```

and

```
a2 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))
```

and also:

```
a2 = list(item for sublist in a for item in sublist)
```

Nothing seems to work. I know this is too basic, but any tips on how to solve this would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Could you fix the syntax errors in your code?  Neither what you have nor what you want are copy-'n-pastable.

Comment: Fixed, thank you for the heads up!

Comment: ?  You have tuples closed by `}`, you have `{,` which is always invalid, etc.  Until you can copy exactly what you've posted and paste it into a fresh interpreter, it's not fixed.  (For that reason, `a.modified` should probably be `a_modified`, too.)

Comment: @DSM No, what I have are dictionaries nested deep inside the tuples, that's what the {}s are doing there. This {'field': (4, 0.75), 'bola': (4, 0.25)} is a dictionary inside the nested tuples. That's why it is so complicated.

Comment: Good grief.  Look at `'animals': (6, 0.1}]])]` -- you don't close the tuple starting with `(6` with `)`.  And look at `{, 'engine': (5, 0.2), [etc]` -- that `{,` is syntactically invalid.  You can easily see the problem simply by doing what I recommended, copying and pasting your own code, and noting the `SyntaxError`; that you didn't bother is disappointing.  If you can't be bothered to make it straightforward for people to help you, you'll find far fewer people will be willing to.

Comment: @DSM, you were right, there were a { missing and a comma that shouldn't be there. Fixed. Sorry for taking your time and thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears you have a list of tuples and linked-list-like structures. Whenever operating on linked-lists, you should think, recursion.

```
def flatten(items):
    from itertools import chain
    def flatten_link(link):
        if isinstance(link, list):
            yield link[0]
            for item in flatten_link(link[1]):
                yield item
        elif link is not None:
            yield link
    return list(tuple(chain(item[:1], flatten_link(item[1]))) for item in items)

a = [
    ('Maria', [1, [2, {'teste': (2, 1.0)}]]),
    ('Lisa ', [2, [4, {'field': (4, 0.75), 'bola': (4, 0.25)}]]), 
    ('John ', [4, [5, {'engine': (5, 0.2), 'wheel': (5, 0.4), 'wheels': (5, 0.2)}]]),
    ('Tracy', [4, [6, {'pizza': (6, 0.16), 'fish': (6, 0.1), 'animals': (6, 0.1)}]]),
]
print(flatten(a))
```

Which yields:

```
[
    ('Maria', 1, 2, {'teste': (2, 1.0)}),
    ('Lisa ', 2, 4, {'bola': (4, 0.25), 'field': (4, 0.75)}),
    ('John ', 4, 5, {'engine': (5, 0.2), 'wheel': (5, 0.4), 'wheels': (5, 0.2)}),
    ('Tracy', 4, 6, {'fish': (6, 0.1), 'animals': (6, 0.1), 'pizza': (6, 0.16)})
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Jeff! That was exactly right! And so clever! :)